# Tesseract does not recognize german "für"

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I use the tesseract 4.0 via docker image [tesseractshadow/tesseract4re](https://github.com/tesseract-shadow/tesseract-ocr-re)

I use the option `-l=deu` to give tesseract the hint, that the text is in "deutsch" (german).

Still the result for the german word "für" is not good. The german word is very common (meaning "for" in english).

Tesseract often detects "fiir" or "fur".

What can I do to improve this?

**reproducible example**

```
docker run --name self.container_name --rm \
    --volume  $PWD:/pwd \
    tesseractshadow/tesseract4re \
    tesseract /pwd/die-fuer-das.png /pwd/die-fuer-das.png.ocr-result -l=deu
```

Result:

```
cat die-fuer-das.png.ocr-result.txt 
die fur das
```

Image die_fuer_das.png:

[image]

Comment: Are you using images with a high enough resolution? Probably the dots of the ü are just a few pixel larger and get interpreted as noise?

Comment: @DanielAlbertini the quality could be better, but the word "für" is easy to see for every german speaking human. I added a reproducible example

Comment: Yes I can confirm that I see the ü ;). But for tesseract it's probably not that easy. The ü dots are both only 3x2px. That's probably too small as you also have white artefacts in the image which are almost similar in size. Sometimes a simple upscaling can be enough for tesseract to get it right. Or you could use some Morphology methods on your image (for example erode)

Comment: the "ü vs ii" issue seems old. Here a message from March 2017. Is tesseract development still alive? https://groups.google.com/d/msg/tesseract-dev/8H_4K3vPRJE/if5IQu9WAwAJ

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the solution. It needs to be `-l deu` otherwise the german language does not get used. I accidentally used `-l=deu`.

Works:

```
===> tesseract  die-fuer-das.png out  -l deu; cat out.txt
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v4.0.0-beta.1-262-g555f with Leptonica
die für das
```

Wrong language:

```
===> tesseract  die-fuer-das.png out  -l=deu; cat out.txt
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v4.0.0-beta.1-262-g555f with Leptonica
die fur das
```